# Antonym of manufacturing

Tags: antonyms

I want to title something based on Chomsky's book [Manufacturing Consent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manufacturing_Consent%3a_The_Political_Economy_of_the_Mass_Media). The text would be about a movement that uses social media to fight against main stream media's attempt to manipulate information. Would "de-manufacturing consent" make sense? Other words that would convey the same idea and still reference the book title?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about *Dismantling Consent*? "Dismantling" -- incidentally the last definition given by Gnawme for "deconstruct" -- seems to convey a careful taking apart of components that suggests the opposite of the careful putting together of components that "manufacturing" suggests.

Answer (score 6):

The title "Deconstructing Consent" may capture what you're after.

> **deconstruct**, *v*. : to break down into constituent parts; dissect; dismantle.

Comment: In criticism, to *deconstruct* refers specifically to an analytical approach associated with Derrida and others. It may or may not be appropriate for the OP, especially for a literary or academic audience.

Comment: you're right choster, hadn't thought of it, I'm going to go with dismantling i think

Comment: @choster Note that the definition of [deconstruct](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/deconstruct?s=t) given in my answer is Dictionary.com's **primary** definition of _deconstruct_. I'm aware of deconstruction as a school of criticism; for those who are conversant with deconstruction -- and don't view it as ["intellectual masturbation"](http://www.science20.com/rationally_speaking/stanley_fish_wrong_again) -- _Deconstructing Consent_ can function as a double-entendre in response and opposition to Chomsky's _Manufacturing Consent_.

Answer (score 5):

*Dismantling* works only if the endpoint of your effort is to see the components of the manufactured consent laid out for view. If, on the other hand, your aim is to undermine fraudulently manufactured consent and foment widespread dissent, then *Demolishing Consent* would better capture your purpose.

Comment: Up vote for "If your aim is to undermine fraudulently manufactured consent and foment widespread dissent..." as it reads well, is accurate re answering the question AND it rhymes.

Answer (score 0):

How about a neologism and a direct connection to Chomsky's title "Un-manufacturing Consent"? It appears the expression is already out there: http://conducivetee.spreadshirt.com/unmanufacture-consent-A8539226

Comment: (This comment is irrelevant. Forgive me?) That garment is over-priced at $28.50. From the product description: "This Shirt is sweat free and organic". I *did* enjoy the company name 'spreadshirt'. Never saw that before!